# Display LI inline and overflow the containing DIV

Tags: css

I have a wrapper that contains an unordered list of banner images, these are going to be a jQuery slider. However, instead of hiding the inactive images using `overflow:hidden` I want to have the images display inline and overflow the containing `<div>`, how do I go about doing this?

```
#slide-wrapper{
    width:760px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
li{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:760px;
    height:340px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: can u show the link of your page

Comment: why have you got the `ul` and `li` inside the `#slide-wrapper` that's not standard and the browser will fail.

Comment: Sorry, i am using the LESS css framework, this is before compiling

Answer (score 0):

Hey now change your code according to this:

```
#slide-wrapper {
    width:760px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:760px;
    height:340px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Didn't see your message about using LESS CSS, amended.

```
#slide-wrapper {
   width:760px;
   float:left;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden; 
ul {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   position:absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
li{
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   width:760px;
   height:340px;
    float:left;
}
```